# Can I on purpose lock the admin out of an Azure SQLDB (as admin)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Can I on purpose lock the admin out of an Azure SQLDB (as admin)

As this may sound as a strange question on first sight. The goal is to only have sql users with data reader & writer rights on the database once the database is setup. Afterwards No accounts should exist anymore that have more rights than Reading & writing to the existing table structure. This behaviour should be irreversible.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. From books online:

> The database user corresponding to the Server admin login cannot be
>   altered or dropped.

Reference: [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse](http://Controlling%20and%20granting%20database%20access%20to%20SQL%20Database%20and%20SQL%20Data%20Warehouse)